# Python: remove last number of a string

Tags: python, logic

I need 4 lines of code to do this script but I think it's possible to do it in 2 (maybe even 1 ! let's dream). Do someone has a solution ?
You can test the code to see the expected result.

```
def remove_nbr_at_the_end_of_the_string(my_str):
    while my_str[-1] in ["0", "1", "2", "3" ,"4" ,"5" ,"6" ,"7" ,"8" ,"9"]:
        my_str = my_str[:-1]
    if my_str[-1] == " ": my_str = my_str[:-1]
    return my_str


for text in ["ACCDS 122", "GR DDF 0332", "MLMD 12 334", "MMED DFE"]:
    print(remove_nbr_at_the_end_of_the_string(text))
```

Comment: `my_str = my_str.rstrip('0123456789')` - and add space to the list of characters to remove if you also want to remove the space before the number.

Comment: `re.sub("\d*$", "", text)` would remove all digits from the end of a string. However, it would stop at non-numeric character (ex spaces).

Comment: If there is 2 numbers at the end of the string, I need to only remove 1. if I had " " to the list, it will remove all nbr at the end, not only the last 1.

Comment: It may be the best optimization: `my_str = my_str.rstrip('0123456789')` thanks for the tips :).

Comment: @Utopion you can easily loop through a list of strings with that same code using a list comprehension like so: `[i.rstrip('0123456789').strip() for i in lst]`

Comment: output of your program has `MLMD 12`. Is that valid?

Comment: Yup, that's the objective, only remove last number, not all the number at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to remove last number as well as space from the end.

```
my_str.rstrip('0123456789').strip()
```

Comment: Turn it into a list comprehension to loop through it like so `[i.rstrip('0123456789').strip() for i in lst]`. This is the most pythonic and shortest answer.

Comment: 1 line of code. No library needed. Pure. I say yes ! thank you for this answer :) (everytime I feel I can't do it more tiny, I ask stack overflow and some random hero prove me I'm wrong !!! I love this website !!!)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line with a regular expression (well, two, for the `import re`):

```
import re

for text in ["ACCDS 122", "GR DDF 0332", "MLMD 12 334", "MMED DFE"]:
    print(re.sub(r" ?\d+$", "", text))
```

which produces:

```
ACCDS
GR DDF
MLMD 12
MMED DFE
```

Note the space before the `?`. That will limit it to removing only one number, plus the space, if there is one. You can replace with `\s` if you want to expand to other forms of whitespace, like tabs.

Also note that, as written, this will remove anything considered a digit in Unicode. If you want to restrict to `0-9`, use this:

```
re.sub(r" ?\d+$", "", text, re.ASCII)
```

And as a future FYI, your while loop condition could be simplified to:

```
while my_str[-1] in "0123456789":
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex

`import re`

```
def remove_nbr_at_the_end_of_the_string(my_str):
  found_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', my_str)
  return my_str.replace(found_numbers[-1], "") if (found_numbers) else my_str
```

this looks for numbers, starting at the end using "r".
if it finds any it will remove the first (from behind), else the string will be returned as it is.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, `rstrip` works pretty well. If you want to create your own rstrip function without any method/other library, something like that can be done too:

```
def my_rstrip(my_str):
    if(my_str[-1] in ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"," ")): return my_rstrip(my_str[:-1])
    return my_str

my_str = "123456qweqsd789 65"
print(my_rstrip(my_str))
>> 123456qweqsd
```

A bit of recursive function never hurts ! (... If your string is not too long i guess ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the occurences of numbers in the end of the string, you can do as follows:

```
def remove_nbr_at_the_end_of_the_string(my_str):
    return [' '.join([j.rstrip('0123456789') for j in i.split()]).strip() for i in my_str]

text = ["ACCDS 122", "GR DDF 0332", "MLMD 12 334", "MMED DFE"]
print(remove_nbr_at_the_end_of_the_string(text))
```

And you'll get:

```
['ACCDS', 'GR DDF', 'MLMD', 'MMED DFE']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly adamant about one-lining it without using rstrip:

```
print("\n".join([string[:len(string)-len(([string[len(string)-i:] for i in range(1, len(string)) if string[len(string)-i:].isdigit()] or [""])[-1])].strip() for string in ["ACCDS 122", "GR DDF 0332", "MLMD 12 334", "MMED DFE"]]))
```

output:

```
ACCDS
GR DDF
MLMD 12
MMED DFE
```

This method creates a list of an expanding window of characters from the right-hand side if they satisfy str.is_digit(), then takes the last element (the biggest valid digit string) of that expanding window list and uses the length of the longest valid digit string to slice the original string. The string is then stripped of whitespace.

There is a particularly sneaky part of this one-liner that makes use of tuple conditional element creation e.g.:

```
([] or [""])
```

Which takes the second element if the first element is false.